# Python: Printing json element in a loop until the JSON is done.

Tags: python, json

so I have JSON that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "className": "Merchant",
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "objectId": "S8IGOwBn8Y"
    },
    {
        "className": "Merchant",
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "objectId": "psNnxwFVmv"
    },

]
```

What i'm interested in is printing each of the objectId's. So far, i've been able to print them individually using:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('test.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)



    pprint(data[x]['objectId'])

    #x is 0 or 1
```

By changing x to 0 or 1 i can manually print them, but what I want is to print them in a for loop until the JSON ends. I've tried things like:

```
    x = 0
    while data[x] != None:

        pprint(data[x]['objectId'])
        x+=1
```

and:

```
data = json.load(data_file)
for line in data_file:
    pprint(data[line]['objectId'])
```

but none of the above give me any output. Anyone have any tips to achieve what I need? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try iterating through the array that you get back from `json.load`:

```
data = json.load(data_file)
for obj in data:
  pprint(obj['objectId'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `json.load(data_file)` should return a list of dictionaries. You can loop through each element of this list and access its dictionary keys and values. Specifically, what you are trying to do can be done as follows:

```
data = json.load(data_file)
for element in data: # data is a list
    print element['objectId'] # element is a dictionary
```

I used `print` because `'objectId'` is a string. If it were a more complex structure you should have used `pprint` instead.